# Setting object fields in a loop in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typing

I have a Feature object (originally from database but in code below I simplified it) and I want to update it:

```
type Feature = {id: number, name: string, deletedAt?: Date}

const newData: Partial<Feature> & {id: number} = {
    id: 1, deletedAt: new Date()
};
const oldFeature: Feature = {
    id: 1, name: 'Abc', deletedAt: undefined
};

for (const key of Object.keys(newData) as (keyof Feature)[]) {
    oldFeature[key] = newData[key];
}
```

Both `oldFeature[key]` and `newData[key]` are of type `string | number | Date | undefined`. But of course for each given key in both objects the type will be one of those above and will be the same. Still, I'm not allowed to make an assignment `oldFeature[key] = newData[key]` because it gives an error:

> Type 'string | number | Date | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)

Why? And how to make it properly?

Comment: Please share min reproducable example

Comment: @captain-yossarian I modified the question to show it

Comment: ```name``` property in ```oldFeature``` has type ```string``` and in ```newData``` it has type ```string | undefined```. They're not compatible. You can't assign ```string | undefined``` to ```strng```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so using a loop is an overkill. All I needed to do is to use object spreading:

```ts
const updated = {
    ...oldFeature,
    ...newData,
}
```

...and the proper fields get updated as needed.